# Typescript comparasion with two indefinides values

Tags: angular, typescript

I'm looking for the best way for this situation:

I have 2 dropdownlist:

```
let combination1: string;
let combination2: string;
```

I have too a **object curriculumVitae** and a **array this object**:

```
obj: Curriculum;
obj.$name;
obj.$age;
obj.$gender;
obj.$country;
obj.$count; //--this value that is increment if two combinations are true...
...and more others properties...

curriculumArray: Array<Curriculum>
```

This array was filled with lot objects in other place and are ok.

Then users can choose 2 diferents values in ddl for show in report after click in button like image below :

In same time, my **component.ts** iterator **curriculumArray** looking for object that **have 2 two parameters equals selected in ddl** and increment this values (zero values of image).

```
for(const i of this.curriculumArray )
{
    if(this.combination1 == i.$name && this.combination2 == i.$age )
    {
    //some value incremented
    }else   
     if(this.combination1 == i.$name && this.combination2 == i.$gender )
    {
    //some value incremented
    }else   
     if(this.combination1 == i.$name && this.combination2 == i.$country )
    {
    //some value incremented
    }else 
     if(this.combination1 == i.$name && this.combination2 == i.$others)
    {
    //some value incremented
    }else 
    if(this.combination1 == i.$gender && this.combination2 == i.$name)
    {
    //filter curriculumArray
    }else 
    if(this.combination1 == i.$name && this.combination2 == i.$others)
    {
    //some value incremented
    }**...and other lot if's**
```

**MY QUESTION IS**: There is some others way for not need use lots if-else for each combination? (gender + age), (gender + country), (gender + religion), (age+ religion), (religion + country), (country+ age) ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would go for a double `for` loop, but maybe using ES6 with `forEach`:

```
curriculumArray.forEach((prop: any) => {
      curriculumArray.forEach((compareProp: any) => {
        if(this.combination1 === prop && this.combination2 === compareProp && prop !== compareProp) {
          // value increment
        }
      })
    });
```

In these 2 loops we'll be checking the combination of the properties and assign values. I don't have more info so I don't know how you'll find out which value to increment, but you can always use maps for that.

Hope it helped!

Comment: I'll try. The value incremented is (this.obj.count++) this value will be incremented always that two combinatios are true in some object that exist in curriculumArray.

Comment: Then I believe it should work! Give it a try and get back to me if you have any issues! ;)